# Running openFDA api locally

Tags: openfda, uses-of-open-data

I am trying to do some classification and clustering on the [openFDA dataset](https://open.fda.gov/). I started by downloading a year's worth of data and realized I run into system limits and would need to solve for that.
Then I decided to query for just one drug indication, the subset I am looking at has about 422k records. But I realized that I hit the skip limit and cannot get the data through the API.

I then decided to run the api locally so as to push through the limits, but I am unable to find clear instructions on how to do it. I have installed node, elasticsearch, and run bootstrap and npm install? I believe I need to run the pipeline, do I just run all-pipelines.sh?

Answer (score 1):

If you need that much data, I'd recommend downloading JSON export files from the Downloads section of a respective endpoint and then doing your data mining on them. Running the pipelines would be more challenging in your case.

Comment: I was able to find a solution. I am iterating through day ranges at a time, so I am able to push through the max skip limit. I initially started with downloaded files, but they are huge and hits system limits. I have installed ijson, so that could help if I need to go back to downloaded data for other aspects.